# Don't understand the deceleration rate of a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I searched for the behaviour of the deceleration rate on a tableview         but I didn't found any good information, so I played myself with values.

I tried the constants UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast from the document, but this is too fast in my case.

I would like to have a very very slow deceleration value, but I don't succeed.

providing < 1. It decelerates very fast.
providing 10000. It decelerates slower, but still decelerates to fast for me. What is the slowest deceleration value I can provide? Or what is the possible range?

```
self.easyTableView.tableView.decelerationRate   = 100000;//UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```

Answer (score 1):

decelerationRate is Scroll View property of float type, you dont have much option with it only 2 mode as describe in doc

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat decelerationRate
```

***Discussion***
Your application can use the UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal and UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast constants as reference points for reasonable deceleration rates.

Comment: No direct way, try to extend scroll view and play with it.